# Why is my Ajax POST request returning an error before the WebApi has responded?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, asp.net-web-api

Apologies if this question is already answered, but I have searched on many related terms with no joy.

I have a simple WebApi controller with a Post method:

```
[HttpPost]
public string Post()
{
    string thing = "hi";
    var jSonSerializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
    var output = jSonSerializer.Serialize(thing);
    return output;
}
```

I also have an Ajax call to above Post method, executed on a button click:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost:58492/WebApi/api/PhysicalActivity',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (response) {
        console.dir(response.status);
    },
    error: function (thing) {
        alert("Ajax call to PhysicalActivity/Post failed");
    }
});
```

The request is definitely getting through to the WebApi post method, because I have a breakpoint set, which is being hit consistently.

However, it does not receive the successful response. The Ajax error callback is being hit.

In fact, I also have a breakpoint set inside the Ajax error callback, and that breakpoint is hit BEFORE the post method breakpoint - so the Ajax call is erroring out before the Post method is even entered.

I have tried returning a string from the Post method, and setting dataType = 'text' in the Ajax call, but that makes no difference.

I have also tried explicitly returning an HttpResponseMessage object from the Post method. It makes no difference.

When I set the contentType to 'text/plain' and the data to 'hello' in the Ajax request, the call doesn't even reach the Post method, and I get a 405 response ('method not allowed').

What am I doing wrong??

Comment: Try to use (F12) developer tools in your browser and check the 'url', it could be routing overriding it..

Comment: Have you checked if your Post Method returns some thing by creating a break point on return statment

Answer (score 0):

try jsonp  for cross orign ajax calls
http://learn.jquery.com/ajax/working-with-jsonp/

Comment: You could provide more explanation of what/why this is cross origin, and how JSONP helps to get around it. This isn't much more than an "RTFM" answer